# How to get rid of "ď»ż" or "ï»¿" characters

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, forms, encoding, utf-8, umbraco

I have website based on Umbraco 5. I have installed contact form plugin (http://cultivjupitercontact.codeplex.com/). 
And on the web page **at the end of this contact form there are always characters "ď»ż"**. It looks like that:

```
...
<input type="submit" value="Send" />        
    </fieldset>         
<input name='uformpostroutevals' type='hidden' value='somevalue' /></form>ď»ż
```

I suspect there is something wrong with encoding. I have tried to change it(to ANSI or UTF-8 without BOM but it didn't helped. Perhaps I have changed it in wrong file, cause I don't really know where exactly this 'ď»ż'is coming from. All I know it came with this plugin.

On different server those extra characters are "ï»¿".

How can I get rid of those extra characters?

Any help much appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to [upgrade to the 5.0.1 patch release](http://umbraco.codeplex.com/releases/view/81440) or later.

This is due to a bug that includes the BOM (Byte order mark) for UTF-8 files as detailed in the bug report ["Text encoding in file when saving the template"](http://issues.umbraco.org/issue/U5-459).

I can verify that upgrading to 5.0.1 fixed the issue.

Comment: Although...you should make the effort to convert your site to Umbraco 7.